# apt-get update for a particular repository

Tags: apt, updates

#### Consider a situation like this:

I am going to install Ubuntu on an UEFI system (dual boot with Windows) where
I need to install `boot-repair`. When I run `sudo apt-get update` it will
update cache for all   the repos. I need to update only a particular `ppa`
(`yannubuntu/boot- repair`) to install `boot-repair`.

Many times I had to update all the repos when I think updating a single `ppa` is enough.

#### Questions

1. Is there any problem/harm if I update only one repo? Can it affect the software installation in any way?
2. If the answer is `No` then how could I update a particular repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any problem/harm if I update only one repo? Can it affect the software installation in any way?

No, well yes, if your package requires a version that is only available from certain repository apt will refuse to install the package.

> If the answer is No then how could I update a particular repo?

You must create the `.list` file where the description of the repository will be, ie:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian raring contrib
```

Then save it somewhere. Now you only have to do:

```
sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="mysources.list"
```

Done.